# update data in one table based on another table data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table A and Table B like below. Where both has account numbers and ID.
I want to find out ID for account number in table B from table A and update the table B with ID value from Table A. I want to make Table A looks like Table B. How to achieve this?

I tried

```
select distinct  A.ID,A.ACCTNO,B.ACCTNO from  TableA as A
inner join TableB as B on A.ACCTNO = B.ACCTNO
```

[image]

my output should be:
[image]

Comment: So What about both null column values?

Comment: what is your expected output..???

Comment: I can ignore NULL values in ACCTNO for time being. But I want to fill ID in Table B from Table A corresponding to ACCTNO.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` with `update`.

**Query**

```
update t1
set t1.ID = t2.ID
from TableB t1
join TableA t2
on t1.ACCTNO = t2.ACCTNO;
```

**Update**

For filling the null rows.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select rn = row_number() over(
        partition by acctno
        order by acctno
    ), *
    from TableB 
),
cte2 as(
    select rn = row_number() over(
        order by acctno
    ), *
    from TableA
    where not exists(
        select 1 from TableB
        where TableA.acctno = TableB.acctno
    )
)
update t1
set t1.Id = t2.Id,
t1.Acctno = t2.Acctno
from cte t1
join cte2 t2
on t1.rn = t2.rn
where t1.Id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update based on join... you can also **neglect null** in ACCTNO for better performance...

```
update B
set B.ID=A.ID
from TableB as B
join TableA as A
on  A.ACCTNO = B.ACCTNO
where B.ACCTNO is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Query:-**

```
update t2
set t2.id=t1.id
from tableB t2
inner join tableA t1
on t2.acctno=t1.acctno
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run both this queries to your desired output

```
INSERT INTO TableB (ID,ACCTNO)
SELECT 
a.ID,
a.ACCTNO 
FROM TableA as a
LEFT JOIN TableB as b on a.ACCTNO = b.ACCTNO
WHERE b.ACCTNO IS NULL;
```

and

```
update b set b.ID = a.ID 
from TableB as b 
left join TableA as a ON a.ACCTNO = b.ACCTNO 
where b.ACCTNO IS NOT null;
```

Answer (score 0):

with a CTE

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT T1.ID AS TABLEA_ID,
                T1.ACCTNO  AS TABLEA_ACCID,
                T2.ID AS TABLEB_ID,
                T2.ACCTNO   AS TANLEB_ACCID
         FROM   TableA T1
                INNER JOIN TableB T2
                  ON T1.ACCTNO= T2.ACCTNO)
UPDATE CTE
SET    TABLEA_ID= TABLEB_ID
```

Hope Its Work !!

Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL will populate table B with the IDs from table A where the acctno matches:

```
UPDATE table_b
SET ID=table_a.id
FROM table_b
INNER JOIN table_a on table_b.acctno=table_a.acctno
```